# blurred @2x images and ios web service data

Tags: ios

Why do @2x images get blurry when they have web service data over them?
Web service data looks pixelated too.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is 'Web service data', some code please ?

Comment: which device get this problem

Comment: Data from the WS is presented over some images. The problem is that all bundled images that are used to display data retrieved from the webservice over them look blurry! values from WS look pixelated too.

Answer (score 0):

You mean, that you are retrieving the image from a webservice? If so, it has nothing to see with a name convention. Images retrieved from a WS must be resized to a proper size. Or just add a parameter to your WS where you can select the size for your image.

The @2x parameter only work for bundled images. If you are downloading them, that won't work.

Comment: Data from the WS is presented over some images. The problem is that all bundled images that are used to display data retrieved from the webservice look blurry!

Answer (score 0):

in your image view try to do not use "Scale to fill" nor "Aspect Fill/Fit" to check if these external images come in correct resolution. If they look smaller than they should - they get blurred on upscaling. Try to provide better res images and use Aspect Fill/Fit (depending on your needs), they'll get downscaled well in pre-retina displays.